# More routes on one map

Tags: google-maps

can I put more than one route on one map?

Here is only one connection

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints.html

For example I have 4 points on one map: A, B, C, D. Two connection A-B, C-D.

Is it possible?

## EDIT

Points A-C and B-D should be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** From Google's own examples you can see [multiple routes](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable.html) on a single map.

Comment: Okey, but here every points are connected. A-C and B-D should be disconnected

Comment: @JoshSmith By any chance, do you know how to clear the routes plotted on OneMap? For example, OneMap.map.graphics.clear() will clear all graphics on the map. But I only wanted to clear the routes plotted but not all graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to compute two different routes and show them (A-B, C-D) as in the examples you have. Just do that twice for each route.

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to clear the routes plotted on OneMap? For example, OneMap.map.graphics.clear() will clear all graphics on the map. But I only wanted to clear the routes plotted but not all graphics.